# Jenkins pipeline error: Tool type maven does not have an install

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using Groovy script to deploy application to server. I want to install latest version of Maven before project gets built using below script.

```
    pipeline {
      agent any

      tools {
          maven "Maven 3.6.3"    
      }
      ....
      stages {
      ....
      }
    }
```

I get this below exception when I run the job.

> Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
> WorkflowScript: 15: Tool type "maven" does not have an install of "Maven 3.6.3" configured - did you mean "Maven-3.3.3"? @ line 15, column 15.
> maven "Maven 3.6.3"

1 error

```
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1085)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:603)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:337)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can anyone suggest what I'm making wrong?

Comment: the error says you dont have that maven version installed in your tools installations. Go to `Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration` there you will see which versions are available to you in the `Maven` section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried the below steps and it worked for me.

1. Dashboard > Manage Jenkins > Global Tools Configuration. Click on Add Maven and mentioned a name and version you want. In my case, I named it as 3.8.5.

Apply the changes

[image]

In the pipeline code, mentioned tools { maven 'NAME_IN_GLOBAL_CONFIGURATION' }

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'main' }
    

    tools {
        maven '3.8.5'
    }
    // ... stages ...///
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following method and it worked for me.
first i changed the maven version to '3.8.6' in Global Tool Configuration

And changed same in the code with maven '3.8.6' shown below

pipeline {
agent any

tools {
maven '3.8.6'
}
stage
{ /// }